# How to prevent toast message when creatin app shortcut icon on homescreen

Tags: android

I want to create app icon on phone screen and i do it but when i do it automatically app creates toast message, How to prevent this toast message when creating app icon or deleting icon on screen? Thanks

**That is code of how i do it**

```
private void addShortcut(){
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    // Shortcut name
   shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
   shortcutIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

   ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(),"."+ this.  getLocalClassName() );
   shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new    Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(comp));

   // Shortcut icon
   ShortcutIconResource iconRes = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this,    R.drawable.icon);
   shortcutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconRes);

   sendBroadcast(shortcutIntent);
}


private void delShortcut(){
    Intent shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    // Shortcut adı
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));

    String appClass = this.getPackageName() + "." +this.getLocalClassName();
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(), appClass);
    shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent   (Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(comp));

    sendBroadcast(shortcut);
}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    delShortcut();
    addShortcut();
```

**Permissions for adding shortcuts**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"> </uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: Nop.I have not found yet.

Answer (score -1):

For your consideration its a bad practice to force app shortcut install. By default the app shortcut will be available on the home screen and its a user choice to disable this behavior in google store app, once the user did it you should not force the opposite.